# TextBlock justify is broken, how to justify a text?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a text which I want it to be justified.

in a TextBlock like this:

```
<TextBlock Width="Auto" TextAlignment="Justify"/>
```

it says it is not supported.

How can I justify a text, in a TextBlock or another control?

Comment: my app is for WP8, I think it doesn't exist there, does it?

Comment: yes it does, add the code from the answer to the .xaml file.

Answer (score 4):

You can workaround it using RichTextBox control:

```
<RichTextBox TextAlignment="Justify" IsReadOnly="True">
    <Paragraph>
        Put your text here
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```